# How do i transfer wordpress backup files from shared hosting to VPS (bluehost)?

Tags: wordpress, database-backups

First of all i am all new to this coding game. Secondly I am having problem transferring wordpress backup files from shared hosting to VPS in bluehost. I have added the host name in the domain provider settings and the main domain is activated but i am having problem with another domain which i have added in the VPS i.e www.artblog.co.in . I have placed the whole public_html folder in the file manager of the same domain but it shows an Error establishing a database connection. Can anybody please help me?

Comment: you need to connect to your MySQL db (please install MySQL if it isn't installed). I am getting a site can't be reached error.

Comment: There are several steps required: 1. Drop all your WP files in the public_html directory (you already did that). 2. If your domain name is changed, you have to replace it in the database export file (use find&replace). 3. Create database and export your database export file (probably file.sql) 4. In the file wp-config.php you have to replace your old database settings with the new ones.

Comment: This is documented: https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: Thanks Shobi, your answer was helpful but i needed it in more detail. My problem is solved :)

Comment: Thank you so much Nikolay! Helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to Migrate Wordpress:

1) Move site files - This is your public_html folder, copy all those files onto your new server

2) Create Database - You will need to create a new database through cPanel. Login and go to MySql Databases and create a new database, while you are there you need to create a new user and grant privileges on the database you just created.

Make notes of the database name, user and password.

3) Go to File Manager and edit public_html/wp-config.php - You need to find these lines and update them with the details you noted in the previous step.

```
/* MySQL settings */
define( 'DB_NAME',     'database_name_here' );
define( 'DB_USER',     'username_here' );
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here' );
define( 'DB_HOST',     'localhost' );
```

4) Log into PHPMyAdmin from your cPanel (Databases/PHPMyAdmin) and import your SQL database that you have from your backup on your shared hosting, into your newly created database.

5) Load up your site admin area, Login, go to "Settings/Permalinks" (Just visiting this page is enough to reset the links).

6) Should be all good!

Edit: This is based on the fact that your domain is the same... If your domain has changed then you will need to replace all instances of your old domain in your database to match the new domain name. Something like SearchReplaceDB works well for this.